# What is the difference between "Ich weiß nicht" and "Das weiß ich nicht"?

Tags: word-order, negation

I think these two sentences have the same meaning, but which one should I use and why?

Comment: The sentence "`Ich weiß nicht`" is colloquial but IMO not complete since it's missing an object. It should read "`Ich weiß es nicht`". `es` or `Das` (in your case) referring to the question (its subject) that someone has been asked for.

Comment: I don't think it's missing an object. It's missing an indirect question which is left out as it is totally clear from the context.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The phrase

> Ich weiß nicht.

is used in colloquial language to express uncertainty, doubt and disagreement, usually when asked for an opinion on something.

For example, I wouldn't be surprised to witness the following dialogue:

(Two girls in a shop)

> A: Was hältst du von diesem Kleid?
>
> B: Ich weiß nicht... - (thinks about it briefly) - Wenn du das nimmst, brauchst du jedenfalls auch passende Schuhe.

It is basically used as a filler in spoken language, much like a doubtful "Hm", to give the speaker a bit of time to think about how to phrase her doubts. Used like this, it is almost always followed by a pause and a more detailed explanation of the cause of the uncertainty.

The meaning depends a lot on context and tone of voice as well as facial expressions etc.

The phrase

> Das weiß ich nicht.

means that the speaker actually does not know some fact.

> A: Hat C seine Prüfung gestern bestanden?
>
> B: Das weiß ich nicht, ich habe seither noch nicht mit ihm gesprochen.

As always when it comes to spoken language, the boundaries are a bit blurry and there are almost certainly regional differences.

Answer (score 4):

In a context where one may say "I don't know" in English without any further elaboration, I think "Weiss ich nicht" would be more common than "Ich weiss nicht." However, other phases like "Keine Ahnung" may well be even more common in practice.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Stack Exchange. While your answer’s details aren’t wrong, I think they just sli~ghtly miss the question. Not too bad in my opinion, but also not good enough to upvote. Do feel welcome and take a [tour] of the site!

Answer (score 2):

1 Weiß nicht.

2 Weiß ich nicht.

3 Ich weiß nicht.

4 Ich weiß es nicht.

5 Das weiß ich nicht.

6 Das weiß ich wirklich nicht.

7 Das weiß ich leider nicht.

8 Keine Ahnung.

9 Ich habe keine Ahnung.

10 Ich habe keine Informationen.

11 Das ist mir nicht bekannt.

Jede dieser Formeln ist möglich.
Ein kleines Kind könnte 1 benützen.
Im lässigen Umgangston, unter Gleichgestellten, wird man 2-5 oder 8/9 hören.
Wenn wir höflicher sein wollen, wird die Formel vollständiger sein.
10/11 ist mehr offizieller Ton.

Answer (score 1):

Ich weiß nicht. = I don't know. (In a very general way. Could be in response to a specific question, where by context it is clear what specific thing you don't know, or could be generally expressing that you are at a loss regarding some topic, e.g. a philosophical question.)

Das weiß ich nicht. = I don't know that. (Refers to the specific piece of information someone sought. May imply that you don't know that, but do know something else.)